# Spread crypto-bot

Tags: exchanges, bots, exchange-software

What do you think is there possibility to write crypto bots using spread beetwen asks and bits? For example: buy currency X for 0.025BTC and then sell X for 0.026 BTC in the same exchanges. As a result we have 4% profit - 2*0.25% (exchanges fee) = 3.5%

Comment: What if no one wants to buy at 0.026 BTC?

Comment: Many exchanges offer an API, and this can be used to write such a bot. As this is not bitcoin related (it concerns any currency), I vote to close this question as being off-topic.

Answer (score 1):

You may rest assured that this is widely happening already, not just with Bitcoin and crypto-currencies, but with other currency markets and the stock exchange.